# Question - Writing Files Back to Local System after Processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am a bit new to PySpark and I am hoping to implement it to speed up the run-time on a script I am using to import physician data in the United States into pdf files for each state and a final csv file for use in a database table. For the sake of practicality since I want to scale up my project to look at regions and provinces in different countries, I want to be able to use PySpark for distributed computing.

I can get processing done much more quickly, but I can't get my files to write back to the local system where I want to use my `multi_part_upload_with_s3` function I wrote in another script to push those files to S3 after I have implemented Spark a bit more. I have here the original script before implementing Spark:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tabula import read_pdf
import requests
import os
from contextlib import closing
from write_to_s3 import multi_part_upload_with_s3

def download_aamc_data(save_folder: str) -> None:
    if not os.path.exists(save_folder):
        os.makedirs(save_folder)

    base_url = 'https://www.aamc.org/system/files/2019-12/state-physician-Alabama-2019%5B1%5D.pdf'

    us_states = ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado",
  "Connecticut","District_of_Columbia","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois",
  "Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland",
  "Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana",
  "Nebraska","Nevada","New_Hampshire","New_Jersey","New_Mexico","New_York",
  "North_Carolina","North_Dakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania",
  "Rhode_Island","South_Carolina","South_Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah",
  "Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West_Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]

    for state in us_states:
        print('Processing {}'.format(state))
        if state != 'Indiana':
            curr_url = base_url.replace('Alabama', state)
        else:
            curr_url = 'https://www.aamc.org/system/files/2019-12/state-physician-Indiana-2019_0.pdf'
        response = requests.get(curr_url, stream=True)
        save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, state + '.pdf')
        with open(save_path, 'wb') as f, closing(requests.get(curr_url)) as res:
           for response, chunk in enumerate(res.iter_content(chunk_size=1024)):
             if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
               f.write(chunk)
               f.flush()
               os.fsync(f.fileno())


def clean_page_single_file(file_path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    state_abbr_dict = {'Alabama': 'AL','Alaska': 'AK','Arizona': 'AZ','Arkansas': 'AR','California': 'CA','Colorado': 'CO','Connecticut': 'CT','District_of_Columbia': 'DC','Delaware': 'DE','Florida': 'FL','Georgia': 'GA','Hawaii': 'HI','Idaho': 'ID','Illinois': 'IL','Indiana': 'IN','Iowa': 'IA','Kansas': 'KS','Kentucky': 'KY','Louisiana': 'LA','Maine': 'ME','Maryland': 'MD','Massachusetts': 'MA','Michigan': 'MI','Minnesota': 'MN','Mississippi': 'MS','Missouri': 'MO','Montana': 'MT','Nebraska': 'NE','Nevada': 'NV',
    'New_Hampshire': 'NH','New_Jersey': 'NJ','New_Mexico': 'NM', 'New_York': 'NY','North_Carolina': 'NC','North_Dakota': 'ND','Ohio': 'OH','Oklahoma': 'OK','Oregon': 'OR','Pennsylvania': 'PA','Rhode_Island': 'RI','South_Carolina': 'SC','South_Dakota': 'SD','Tennessee': 'TN','Texas': 'TX','Utah': 'UT','Vermont': 'VT','Virginia': 'VA','Washington': 'WA','West_Virginia': 'WV','Wisconsin': 'WI','Wyoming': 'WY'}
    state_name = file_path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    state_code = state_abbr_dict[state_name]
    
    df = read_pdf(file_path, pages = 'all')
    p1 = df[0].copy(deep=True)
    p2 = df[1].copy(deep=True)

    p1.columns = list('abcde')
    p1 = p1.iloc[2:]
    p1['a'] = p1['b']
    p1 = p1[['a', 'c']]
    p1 = p1.iloc[:19]
    
    p1 = p1.transpose()
    new_header = p1.iloc[0]
    p1 = p1.iloc[1:]
    p1.columns = new_header
    p1.insert(0, 'State', [state_code])
    p1 = p1.reset_index()
    del p1['index']
    p1.columns.name = None
    p1 = p1.replace('---', 'NA')
    
    p2_columns = ['Speciality', 'Physicians', 'People per Physicians', 'Total female Physicians', 'Percent Female Physicians', 'Total Physicians > Age 60', 'Percent Physicians > Age 60']
    p2.columns = p2_columns
    p2 = p2.replace('*', 'NA')
    p2 = p2[['Speciality', 'Physicians']]
    p2 = p2.transpose()
    
    new_header = p2.iloc[0]
    p2 = p2.iloc[1:]
    p2.columns = new_header
    del p2['SpecialtyPhysiciansPeople Per PhysicianNumberPercentNumberPercent']
    p2.insert(0, 'State', [state_code])
    p2 = p2.reset_index()
    del p2['index']
    p2.columns.name = None
    
    p1 = p1.join(p2, rsuffix = '_p2')
    del p1['State_p2']
    
    return(p1)

def clean_all_documents(folder_path: str, save_path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    assert os.path.exists(folder_path)
    
    pdf_list = os.listdir(folder_path)
    pdf_list = list(filter(lambda x: '.DS_Store' not in x, pdf_list))
    pdf_list.sort()
    print('Processing file {}'.format(pdf_list[0]))
    master_df = clean_page_single_file(os.path.join(folder_path, pdf_list[0]))

    for pdf in pdf_list[1:]:
        print('Processing file {}'.format(pdf))
        curr_path = os.path.join(folder_path, pdf)
        curr_df = clean_page_single_file(curr_path)
        master_df = master_df.append(curr_df)
    
    print('Saving csv to disk.')
    master_df.to_csv(save_path)
    master_df = master_df.reset_index()
    del master_df['index']
    
    return(master_df)

def main():
    print('Downloading data.')
    save_folder = './healthcare_pdf'
    download_aamc_data(save_folder = save_folder)
    
    print('Processing pdfs.')
    folder_path = save_folder
    save_path = './national_physicians.csv'
    clean_all_documents(folder_path= folder_path, save_path=save_path)

    multi_part_upload_with_s3("my-bucket", "pdf-directory" , "pdf")
    multi_part_upload_with_s3("my-bucket", "csv-directory", "csv")    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The new script after implementing Spark:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from tabula import read_pdf
#try:
#    from tabula import read_pdf
#except ImportError:
#    import subprocess
#    subprocess.run(['pip3', 'install', '--user', 'tabula-py'], check=True)
#    from tabula import read_pdf
import requests
import os
from contextlib import closing
from write_to_s3 import multi_part_upload_with_s3
from concurrent import futures
sys.path.append('../utilities')
from utility_setup import create_spark


def generate_url(state):
    base_url = 'https://www.aamc.org/system/files/2019-12/state-physician-{}-2019%5B1%5D.pdf'
    if state != 'Indiana':
        curr_url = base_url.format(state)
    else:
        curr_url = 'https://www.aamc.org/system/files/2019-12/state-physician-Indiana-2019_0.pdf'
    return curr_url

def download_aamc_data(save_folder: str) -> None:
    if not os.path.exists(save_folder):
        os.makedirs(save_folder)

    us_states = ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado",
  "Connecticut","District_of_Columbia","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois",
  "Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland",
  "Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana",
  "Nebraska","Nevada","New_Hampshire","New_Jersey","New_Mexico","New_York",
  "North_Carolina","North_Dakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania",
  "Rhode_Island","South_Carolina","South_Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah",
  "Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West_Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]

    urls = {state:generate_url(state) for state in us_states}

    for state, curr_url in urls.items():
        response = requests.get(curr_url, stream=True)
        save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, state + '.pdf')                                                                                                                                                              
        with open(save_path, 'wb') as f, closing(requests.get(curr_url)) as res:
           for response, chunk in enumerate(res.iter_content(chunk_size=1024)):
             if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
               f.write(chunk)
               f.flush()
               os.fsync(f.fileno())


def clean_page_single_file(file_path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    state_abbr_dict = {'Alabama': 'AL','Alaska': 'AK','Arizona': 'AZ','Arkansas': 'AR','California': 'CA','Colorado': 'CO','Connecticut': 'CT','District_of_Columbia': 'DC','Delaware': 'DE','Florida': 'FL','Geor$    'New_Hampshire': 'NH','New_Jersey': 'NJ','New_Mexico': 'NM', 'New_York': 'NY','North_Carolina': 'NC','North_Dakota': 'ND','Ohio': 'OH','Oklahoma': 'OK','Oregon': 'OR','Pennsylvania': 'PA','Rhode_Island': 'R$    state_name = file_path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    state_code = state_abbr_dict[state_name]

    df = read_pdf(file_path, pages = 'all')
    p1 = df[0].copy(deep=True)
    p2 = df[1].copy(deep=True)

    p1.columns = list('abcde')
    p1 = p1.iloc[2:]
    p1['a'] = p1['b']
    p1 = p1[['a', 'c']]
    p1 = p1.iloc[:19]

    p1 = p1.transpose()
    new_header = p1.iloc[0]
    p1 = p1.iloc[1:]
    p1.columns = new_header
    p1.insert(0, 'State', [state_code])
    p1 = p1.reset_index()
    del p1['index']
    p1.columns.name = None
    p1 = p1.replace('---', 'NA')

    p2_columns = ['Speciality', 'Physicians', 'People per Physicians', 'Total female Physicians', 'Percent Female Physicians', 'Total Physicians > Age 60', 'Percent Physicians > Age 60']
    p2.columns = p2_columns
    p2 = p2.replace('*', 'NA')
    p2 = p2[['Speciality', 'Physicians']]
    p2 = p2.transpose()

    new_header = p2.iloc[0]
    p2 = p2.iloc[1:]
    p2.columns = new_header
    del p2['SpecialtyPhysiciansPeople Per PhysicianNumberPercentNumberPercent']
    p2.insert(0, 'State', [state_code])
    p2 = p2.reset_index()                                                                                                                                                                                              
    del p2['index']
    p2.columns.name = None

    p1 = p1.join(p2, rsuffix = '_p2')
    del p1['State_p2']

    return(p1)

def clean_all_documents(folder_path: str, save_path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    assert os.path.exists(folder_path)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    pdf_list = os.listdir(folder_path)
    pdf_list = list(filter(lambda x: '.DS_Store' not in x, pdf_list))
    pdf_list.sort()
    # print('Processing file {}'.format(pdf_list[0]))
    # master_df = clean_page_single_file(os.path.join(folder_path, pdf_list[0]))

    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as exc:
        dfs = exc.map(clean_page_single_file, [os.path.join(folder_path, pdf) for pdf in pdf_list])
    master_df = pd.concat(dfs)

    #for pdf in pdf_list[1:]:#for pdf in pdf_list[1:]:
    #    print('Processing file {}'.format(pdf))
    #    curr_path = os.path.join(folder_path, pdf)
    #    curr_df = clean_page_single_file(curr_path)
    #    master_df = master_df.append(curr_df)

    print('Saving csv to disk.')
    master_df.to_csv(save_path)
    master_df = master_df.reset_index()
    del master_df['index']

    return(master_df)


def process_on_spark():
    us_states = ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado",
  "Connecticut","District_of_Columbia","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois",
  "Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland",
  "Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana",
  "Nebraska","Nevada","New_Hampshire","New_Jersey","New_Mexico","New_York",
  "North_Carolina","North_Dakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania",
  "Rhode_Island","South_Carolina","South_Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah",
  "Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West_Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]
    
   urls = [(state, generate_url(state)) for state in us_states]

    sc = create_spark() # app=None, mem=None)
    result = sc.sparkContext.parallelize(urls).map(download_and_extract_dataframe).collect()
    master_df = pd.concat(result)

    print('Saving csv to disk.')
    save_path = './national_physicians.csv'
    master_df.to_csv(save_path)
    master_df = master_df.reset_index()
    del master_df['index']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                multi_part_upload_with_s3("covid19datalakesafford", "/home/ubuntu/insight-fellows-de2020-pandemic-platform/data_fetching_etl/healthcare_pdf" , "pdf")
    multi_part_upload_with_s3("covid19datalakesafford", "/home/ubuntu/insight-fellows-de2020-pandemic-platform/data_fetching_etl", "csv")
    return(master_df)


def download_and_extract_dataframe(state_url):

    #try:
    #    from tabula import read_pdf
    #except ImportError:
    #    import subprocess
    #    import subprocess                                                                                                                                                                                             #    subprocess.run(['pip3', 'install', '--user', 'tabula-py'], check=True)
    #    from tabula import read_pdf                                                                                                                                                                               
    save_folder = '.' # /downloaded_pdfs'
    # this doesn't seem to work
    #if not os.path.isdir(save_folder):                                                                                                                                                                                #    os.makedirs(save_folder)                                                                                                                                                                                      
    state, curr_url = state_url
    response = requests.get(curr_url, stream=True)                                                                                                                                                                     
    save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, state + '.pdf')                                                                                                                                                              
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as f, closing(requests.get(curr_url)) as res:                                                                                                                                               
       for response, chunk in enumerate(res.iter_content(chunk_size=1024)):                                                                                                                                                   
          if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
               f.write(chunk)
               f.flush()
               os.fsync(f.fileno())

    df = clean_page_single_file(save_path)
    return df


def main():
    print('Downloading data.')
    save_folder = './healthcare_pdf'
    download_aamc_data(save_folder = save_folder)                                                                                                                                                                  
    print('Processing pdfs.')
    folder_path = save_folder
    save_path = './national_physicians.csv'                                                                                                                                                                            clean_all_documents(folder_path= folder_path, save_path=save_path)                                                                                                                                             
    multi_part_upload_with_s3("my-bucket", "pdf-directory" , "pdf")                                                              multi_part_upload_with_s3("my-bucket", "csv-directory", "csv")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                                                             main()
    # process_on_spark()
```

For my function (comes from another Python script):

```
def multi_part_upload_with_s3(bucket, path, extension):
    # Multipart upload
    """Multipart upload for files downloaded from urls/S3"""
    #create s3 object
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    os.chdir(path)
    config = TransferConfig(
    multipart_threshold=2*1024*1024,
    max_concurrency=5,
    num_download_attempts=10,
    multipart_chunksize=1024*1024,
    max_io_queue=100)
    result = glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))

    for file in result:
       try:
         print('Upload:', file)
         s3.Bucket(bucket).upload_file(file,'{}'.format(file), Config=config, Callback=ProgressPercentage(file))
         os.remove(file)                                                                                                                                                                                                  except Exception as e:
          print('Upload:', file, 'failed')
          print(e)
```

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to go about crafting the Python script implementing Spark in order to bring the processed data back to the files on my local instance from my workers and using my function to write to S3?

EDIT: I am trying to stick with Tabula-Py for now. In terms of time to process on the original script and the attempt to use PySpark as benchmarks:

Executing the original script as a Spark job on my cluster:

```
real    2m33.090s
user    2m5.460s
sys     0m5.198s
```

Executing with the Spark attempt script on my cluster:

```
real    2m38.746s
user    2m6.520s
sys     0m5.339s
```